# Application.Run(new Form1()); giving error

Tags: c#

i have the standard code for Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cellap
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

1. i created a new project
2. i imported an existing form1 into it and replaced the existing form1
3. when i run the app, i get an error on the mentioned line:

   Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\alexluvsdanielle\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\cellap\Program.cs    18  33  cellap

does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you actually have a `Form1` class?

Comment: where could i find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using ProjectName.folder
```

Then create an object for the Form1() class like this.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
```

Also, make sure you actually have a Form1.cs

Answer (score 2):

Check your namespace. The *existing* `Form1` is more than likely in a different namespace than `cellap`. Check the `Form1.designer.cs` class too.

Answer (score 2):

When you copied the Form did you change it's namespace so the Program.cs can actually see it?