# Increment a xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows, launcher

Ok so i have run into a bind with my work. I have a xml document i am trying to change. The value has to change every time a file has downloaded. So basically when file A finishes downloading version.xml has a id that i want to change from "0" to "1". Now with this i can finally set up my launcher the way i want it to be here the code that i have.

```
private void GetNextNodeID()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"version.xml");
        var x = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Product");
        int Max = 0;



        Max++
        XmlElement newElement = doc.CreateElement("Product");
        newElement.SetAttribute("id", Max.ToString());

        doc.Save(@"version.xml");

    }
```

also here is the xml document

```
<Table>
<Product>
<Product>0</Product>
<Product_name>Vitare</Product_name>
<Product_version>1.0.0.1</Product_version>
</Product>
</Table>
```

Now for some reason the code never messes with the xml file please help me figure out how to increment the value!!!!!!!!!

Thank you , Devin Magaro

Comment: The code you've given doesn't even *compile*...

Comment: @Devin Magaro there is a missing `;` after `Max++`

Comment: i used what jon skeet gave me and it gives me a An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're creating a new element using the document, but never actually adding it to the document. You're also trying to set an *attribute* where previously you had the text within the element itself.

Assuming you really do just want to update the element, I'd personally use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("version.xml");
// Single() ensures there's only one such element
var element = doc.Descendants("Product").Single(); 
int currentValue = (int) element;
element.SetValue(currentValue + 1);
doc.Save("version.xml");
```

If you want to update *all* `Product` elements, you should loop over `doc.Descendants("Product")` with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Now when i run the code and my download finishes i get an error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  It happens when im calling the private void from when the download completes

Comment: it also points to the Application.Run(new form1()); when the error pops up

Comment: @Devin Magaro The problem you have has nothing to do with Jon Skeet's code but visibly you are trying to display this data on WinForms. [You can look @ this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182675/application-runnew-form1-giving-error). On the other, Jon's code won't work with the XML file you have given, you will probably have en error like `Sequence contains more than one element `  since you define two times `<Product>` tag. Try to give another name to the outer tag (something like `<Products>`.